# System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot resolve 'channel' template reference: 'http client'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

I make a EventReciever:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

namespace AlertLists.Alerts{

  public class Alerts : SPItemEventReceiver{

    public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties){

      base.ItemAdding(properties);
      properties.ListItem["title"] = "OK";
      properties.ListItem.Update();

    }

  }

}
```

Other information: It Wasn't applicate in Farm Solution

The ListTemplateId is

I deploy the solution in Visual Studio 2012 on the server `Windows Server 2012`

When add item in personalized List, show me the error:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: An attempt to connect to 
the remote activator failed with exception
'System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot resolve 'channel'
template reference: 'http client'.
```

Why? Help me please!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, this fixes the problem for me on SharePoint 2013 instance installed on a Windows Domain Controller:

Set-SPLogLevel -Identity "SharePoint Foundation:Sandboxed Code Service" -TraceSeverity "Verbose"

Restart-Service -Name "SharePoint User Code Host"

Of course, I only use this in a non-production environment.